# How to return the result of a async function to a different class in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, asynchronous

I'm working on retrieving some data via scraping in Swift and I'm having trouble passing the data between classes in my project.

Right now the functions successfully grab the data and can print it to the console, but I can't get the data back to the ViewController class.

Here's ViewController

```swift
    @IBAction func tester(sender: UIButton) {       
        var xx = "DON'T PRINT THIS"

        xx = grabTheDeetz()

        print(xx)
    }
```

and here's grabTheDeetz(). I'm looking to return data back to ViewController.

```swift
    print("starting")
    var x = ""
    rip(onSuccess: {
        data in
        print(data)
    })
    return x
//////////////////////////////
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {(data, response, error) in

            guard let data = data else {
                print("data was nil")
                return
            }

            guard let htmlString = String(data: data, encoding: .shiftJIS) else {
                print("couldn't cast data into String")
                return
            }

            //print(htmlString)
            success(htmlString)

        }

        task.resume()
```

I know the data is being successfully retrieved, I'm just trying to get it back to the right place where it can be handled properly.

Functions after it in ViewController run before the data can be returned. (In this case, on button press "DON'T PRINT THIS" will always be printed, the the print(htmlString) will print the correct data.)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a callback function like this and get back response from this function to any other controller.

```
private func process(using request:URLRequest, closure:@escaping (Error?, Any?) -> ()) {
    let urlSessionTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        var responseData:Any?
        var errorResponse:Error?

        closure(errorResponse, responseData)
    })
    urlSessionTask.resume()
}
```